# React Hooks, prop value changing randomly between renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert a class component, which is a Gatsby Layout component, to a functional component using react hooks to manage state. My goal here is to open a modal once we reach a certain point in page and scroll up.

The problem I'm facing is that one prop I'm passing to this Layout component (TrustedInView, see code below), is changing value between renders, as console logs show it. So I'm confused about what's happening there. I expect the value of the prop to always be the same since the value logged in index.js is not changing (and not supposed to).

This is the code in the layout component :

```js
// Hook
const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
};

let notOpenedYet = true;
// Layout component
const Layout = ({ intl, children, trustedInView }) => {
  const [modalIsOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  // Get the previous value (was passed into hook on last render)
  let prevPosition = usePrevious(window.scrollY);

  const handleNavigation = e => {
    const custWindow = e.currentTarget;
    if (prevPosition > custWindow.scrollY) {
      console.log('trustedInView when goes up:', trustedInView);
      if (trustedInView && notOpenedYet) {
        notOpenedYet = false;
        setTimeout(() => setOpen(true), 1500);
      }
    }
    prevPosition = custWindow.scrollY;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add event listener when component mounts:
    window.addEventListener('scroll', e => handleNavigation(e));
    // Remove event listener when component unmounts:
    return window.removeEventListener('scroll', e => handleNavigation(e));
  });
```

Here is the index.js render method with the layout component  :

```js
 render() {
    const { intl } = this.props;
    const { activeVideo, tabs, tabNumber, trustedInView } = this.state;
    const features = [
      // some objects
    ];
    console.log('trustedInView in index :', trustedInView);
    return (
      <Layout trustedInView={trustedInView}>
```

And this is the console logs :

[I expect the value of the prop to always be the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8IT2.png)

Can anyone set me on track?

Comment: Can you post the code for `index.js`?

Comment: you should read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Matching_event_listeners_for_removal

Comment: if you want `useEffect` to run only on mount, you should pass `[]` as a second argument. Otherwise it will be called on each render.

Comment: `removeEventListener` needs to get **referentially** the same listener function to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new listener is being set up in every render and is never removed. So in subsequent scrolls, you are actually seeing more than one console.log per event, some of them have captured a different `trustedInView` via the closure making it seem that the value is changing when it is not.

There are several problems with this code

1. `useEffect` doesn't have any dependencies, so it's being called on every render
2. `useEffect` `removeEventListener` is not really being called when the component unmounts, useEffect expected you to return a function and you are returning whatever the result of removeEventListener is.
3. You are not removing any listener since you are creating a new function and passing it `removeEventListener` instead of the function passed to `addEventListener` another function created everytime.
4. Every render has a new version of `handleNavigation` so even if we were to fix the previous errors we have to make sure that we remove the correct listener. Luckily this is what `useCallback` is for.

Taking those things into account will look something like this:

```js
const handleNavigation = useCallback(() => { /* ... */ }, [prevPosition, trustedInView])

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleNavigation);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleNavigation);
  }
}, [handleNavigation])
```

But even this is problematic since the `prevPosition` is going to change every time destroying the effect, plus is going to get stale for your purposes.  So its better just to use a ref directly without your `usePrevious` hook

```js
const prevValueRef = useRef(0);

const handleNavigation = useCallback(e => {
  const scrollY = e.currentTarget.scrollY;
  const prevScrollY = prevValueRef.current;

  // Save the value for the next event
  prevValueRef.current = scrollY;

  // ...

}, [trustedInView])
```

Comment: Hi @Mon Villalon, thanks it works great now ! However I'm not sure how putting handleNavigation as second argument of useEffect works. Is it due to the changing value of scrollY inside it that determines that the effect is being called ?

Comment: Every variable a function or other that is used inside an useEffect (or useMemo / useCallback)  should be specified in an array as the second argument of the hook or weird stuff is going to happen because of closures capturing values.  It is too long to explain in a comment but look at
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html